# Problems with objects passing string using polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm having trouble with adding some strings to an object using polymorphism. The first object that goes through gets the Strings, however the second object I pass strings to doesn't obtain it for some reason. I'm sorry if I posted too much code, I wasn't quite sure what parts are important to find out what was wrong.

Here is the code

```
public class Publication {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    List <Book> list = new ArrayList <Book>();

    Book bookOne = new Periodical("Harry Potter", "House", "2000", "Fantasy");
    bookOne.setPubFreq("Yearly");
    bookOne.setEditor("Dave");

    Book bookTwo = new Book("Game of Thrones", "Lanister", "2000", "Fantasy");
    bookTwo.setPubFreq("Yearly");
    bookTwo.setEditor("George");

    System.out.print(bookOne);
    System.out.print(bookTwo);
}
```

With the main methond above, I'm trying to pass the string, the first one prints fine like this

```
Book Title               :Harry Potter
Publisher                :House
Publication date         :2000
Subject                  :Fantasy
Publication Frequency    :Yearly
Editor                   :Dave
```

however the bookTwo doesn't include Publication Frequency or editor for some reason.

Here is the rest of the code, I suspect it has something to do with the abstract.

```
public class Periodical extends Book {

  private String pubFreq, editor;
  //CONSTRUCTOR
  public Periodical(String title, String publisher, String publicationDate, String subject) {
    super(title, publisher, publicationDate, subject);
  }

  //PUBLICATION FREQUENCY
  public String getPubFreq() {
    return pubFreq;
  }

  public void setPubFreq(String bookPubFreq) {
      this.pubFreq = bookPubFreq;
    }
    //EDITOR
  public String getEditor() {
    return editor;
  }

  public void setEditor(String bookEditor) {
    this.editor = bookEditor;
  }

  public String toString() {
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer(super.toString());
    strBuf.append("\nPublication Frequency    :");
    strBuf.append(pubFreq);
    strBuf.append("\nEditor                   :");
    strBuf.append(editor);

    return strBuf.toString();
  }



}
```

```
public class Book {

  private String title, publisher, publicationDate, subject;
  //CONSTRUCTOR
  Book() {
    setTitle("");
    setPublisher("");
    setPublicationDate("");
    setSubject("");
  }

  Book(String title, String publisher, String publicationDate, String subject) {
    setTitle(title);
    setPublisher(publisher);
    setPublicationDate(publicationDate);
    setSubject(subject);
  }

  //TITLE
  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String bookTitle) {
      this.title = bookTitle;
    }
    //PUBLISHER
  public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
  }

  public void setPublisher(String bookPublisher) {
      this.publisher = bookPublisher;
    }
    //PUBLICATION DATE

  public String getPublicationDate() {
    return publicationDate;
  }

  public void setPublicationDate(String bookPublicationDate) {
      this.publicationDate = bookPublicationDate;
    }
    //SUBJECT

  public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
  }

  public void setSubject(String bookSubject) {
    this.subject = bookSubject;
  }

  public String toString() {
      return ("Book Title               :" + title + "\n" +
        "Publisher                :" + publisher + "\n" +
        "Publication date         :" + publicationDate + "\n" +
        "Subject                  :" + subject);
    }
    //ABSTRACT
  public void setPubFreq(String string) {

  }

  public void setEditor(String string) {

  }


}
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't, you don't do anything with publication-frequency in the `Book` class...

Comment: As I'm new to java I do not know if it is correct, but I thought the abstract methods were supposed to be empty. The `Periodical class` has the setter and getter methods for the abstract methods `setPubFreq` and `setEditor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not declaring the setEditor and setPubFreq as abstract in the Book class. If you want them to be abstract, you have to declare them like this:

```
public abstract void setPubFreq(String string);
public abstract void setEditor(String string);
```

You would also have to declare the whole class as abstract - it won't be able to be instantiated then. If this is not your intention, you can either use a interface that declares these two methods and make your Book and Periodical class implement it or make yet another abstract class that Book extends from and that has only these two methods, declared as abstract.

But i think you probably just want to do this:

```
Book bookTwo = new Periodical("Game of Thrones", "Lanister", "2000", "Fantasy");
```

instead of:

```
Book bookTwo = new Book("Game of Thrones", "Lanister", "2000", "Fantasy");
```

Just like you did with bookOne.

Comment: Oh of course, thank you very much. That fixed the issue I was having. I thought I had changed everything to have `new Periodical` but I didn't and that's what was messing me up. Thank you very much for the help!